# GUI in assembly

Tags: user-interface, assembly

Is there a way to create a GUI in 16-bit ASM.  I am trying to create an Operating System and have so far had no errors, but I am wondering how this is done.  Having done both a Stack Overflow and Google search that has returned no answers I have decided to ask this question myself and see whether it is possible.

Comment: Why 16-bit assembly, out of curiosity, and what target architecture (CPU)?

Comment: Sure it's possible, for examples look at many old DOS utilities and games. If you're just starting out, a [Text-based user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) is probably more manageable.

Comment: Check [MenuetOS](http://www.menuetos.net/) and FreeDOS.

Comment: The old Borland tool sets include a text based GUI. Windows 3.1 can run on a 286 (protected 16 bit mode) IBM OS/2 1.0 can run on a 286 (protected 16 bit mode). Digital Research's GEM could run on MSDOS (not sure if real mode or protected 16 bit mode).

Comment: Windows 2.1 could run in 16-bit real mode on DOS (Actually, Windows/386 could too if you ran win86.com instead of win386.exe to start it!).  DeskMate was a 16-bit DOS GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am time traveler from the future looping in the past.

What does makes it wrong when using only a 16-bit ASM code for starting to program a gui example for a 16 bit application in the realmode, exacly why a beginner should not start learning first the 16 bit programming, example before to learn how to use the Intel's AVX 512-bit SIMD instructions?

It is really so wrong and a mistake? I think it is not wrong and it is not a mistake.
So i think it is more a good choice by learning step by step and not jumping over so far away from the roots. First starting with looking "how the Linux kernel works" is for beginners is step much to far and not very usefull for programming only a first simple GUI.

..

Within the 16 bit realmode it is possible to write directly to the graphic ram and we can see the result imediatly, so we can learn much faster what is happend if our code fail, or it is OK. And there is no trouble with the protection_"crap" that comes within modern operation systems. (On this way nobody can see how exactly our content comes to the screen and this is a big black hole for beginners to understand.)

Within the 16 bit realmode it is possible to use a lot of bios software interrupts, some for to change the videomode and the resolution of modern graphic cards with a VBE3 bios comming with modenumbers for widescreen LCD monitors for to fit their native resolution. More details are in the "vbe3.pdf" from vesa.org.

(In the future all CPUs use only one bit and only one address in space. No one need more.)

Dirk

Answer (score 8):

Please don't take this the wrong way, but I believe this is a case where "if you have to ask, you aren't ready." Also note that there is a *huge* difference between "writing your own GUI" in assembly, and "writing your own *operating system*". The latter entails things like creating a virtual memory manager, a file system, a task scheduler, and basic I/O functionality. It is far, *far* beyond the capabilities of a beginner. Even writing a GUI in an existing operating system is a very challenging task in assembly.

**Don't be discouraged from trying to learn, though.** If this is just curiosity, and you want to learn how modern operating systems work at a low level, try some Google searches for "how the Linux kernel works." There are several excellent articles which don't require expert knowledge and give some good insights into how these things work. You can also search for more specific terms to learn about the various pieces of an operating system (task scheduling, virtual memory management, etc.).

If you already know assembly, you can probably even follow a tutorial in creating a basic bootable image in x86. From there you can start playing around with a "raw" environment.

In particular, I recommend the [articles and tutorials on **osdev.org**](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) which have helped me in playing around with this stuff.

Comment: Thank you.  I will consider this in mind and I will look at the tutorials on osdev.org.  You just made my life easier.